# Exo- player gets source error when songs are continuously played in just audio player but next function works fine

Tags: node.js, flutter, just-audio, background-audio, audio-service

Source code :

_managePlayer(List playlist) async {
Iterable pList = playlist.reversed;

```
final _playerplaylist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
    children: pList
        .map(
          (song) => AudioSource.uri(
            Uri.parse(song.media_Link),
            tag: MediaItem(
              id: song.id,
              album: song.artist,
              title: song.song_title,
              artUri: Uri.parse(song.lg_thumbnail),
            ),
          ),
        )
        .toList());
try {
  await _miniPlayer.setAudioSource(_playerplaylist);
  _miniPlayer.play();
} catch (e) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

}

When just_audio player plays 4 songs continuously, the player stops playing and keeps on loading.

In console, I get the given below error.

Error :

/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): Playback error

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:616)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:413)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:263)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1005)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4844): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

E/AudioPlayer( 4844): TYPE_SOURCE: Response code: 403

The player should play all the songs continuously till the playlist is completed.